# ¿Por qué no funciona la regla 'minCount[1]' en Form Validation de Semantic UI?

Tags: jquery

Buen día.

Estoy usando "Form Validation" de Semantic UI para validar un formulario.

El problema surge cuando quiero validar un campo "select" con selección múltiple, según la documentación se debe hacer así:

```
name: {
    identifier: 'name',
    rules: [
      {
        type   : 'minCount[1]'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Mi código esta igual (obviamente cambiando el nombre del campo) pero no logra validar y es solo con ese campo, con los demás no tengo problemas.

Gracias de antemano.

Mi código:

```
 $(document).on("ready", function(){
  var form = $("#form_empresa");
  form.on("submit", function(ex){
    ex.preventDefault()
  }).form({
    on : "submit",
    fields : {
      empresa: {
        identifier  : 'empresa',
        rules: [
          {
            type   : 'minLength[5]',
          }
        ]
      },
      categorias: {
        identifier  : 'categorias',
        rules: [
          {
            type   : 'minCount[1]',
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    onSuccess : function(){...
```

Comment: Diego, asegúrate de incluir un [mcve]. El código que copias de internet, seguramente funciona y entonces no podemos verificar tu problema.